# HTML :first-child not giving desire result

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

The code below appends the content before first-child of .current and .done

```css
.current:first-child::before  {
 content: 'Current ';
    color: blue
}

.done:first-child::before {
 content: 'Done ';
    color: red
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
  <li class="current">The first li.</li>
  <li class="done">The second li.</li>
  <li class="done">The third li.</li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

I am unable to understand why the content "Done" is not appended before "The second li" even though it is the first-child of .done (.done:first-child::before)

Comment: You gotto use `:nth-child()` instead of `:first-child`

Answer (score 1):

Use `:nth-child(n)`
**Learn about it:**https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

**In your case you want only the first so use `nth-child(2)`**

```css
.current:first-child::before  {
 content: 'Current ';
    color: blue
}

.done:nth-child(2)::before {
 content: 'Done ';
    color: red
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
  <li class="current">The first li.</li>
  <li class="done">The second li.</li>
  <li class="done">The third li.</li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

This will work also when multiple classes `.current` or `.red` are present.

```css
.current > .current::before  {
 content: 'Current ';
  color: blue
}

.done > .done::before {
 content: 'Done ';
  color: red
}

ul li:not(.done):first-child::before {
  content: 'Current ';
  color: blue;
}

ul li:not(.done) + .done::before {
  content: 'Done';
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
  <li class="current">The first li.</li>
  <li class="current">The first li.</li>
  <li class="current">The first li.</li>
  <li class="done">The second li.</li>
  <li class="done">The third li.</li>
  <li class="done">The third li.</li>
  <li class="done">The third li.</li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It does not accomplish the goal to only apply rules to first .done element

Comment: @Arthur Cantarela you right edited answer!!

Comment: If the second <li> is not .done, it does not work still. You must use :first-of-type pseudo class

Comment: I edited my awnser into your awnser as I had a nice solution when  they just closed it :|

Comment: @Red nice one....